# GhostScript (PostScript): Printer cut- off borders when scaling down from A* to A4

Tags: c, ghostscript, postscript

I'm working on a "GS Wrapper" (using the 9.20 SDK) for use by an external application. There i scale down for example a A0 Sheet to A1, A2 and A3 and it works fine. (PDF to PS, then Print)

Problem: When i scale down any input format to A4, the printer cut off the borders of the content (these are technical drawings with a black border each 5mm from the sheet edge).

- Is there an opportunity to scale down the A4 (to A4) again about 95% and center the image? (This should be result in a smaller base image, say the black borders are about ~10mm away from the sheet border afterwards)

I use the following parameter for scaling:

```
GhostArg[0] = "-dNOPAUSE";
GhostArg[1] = "-dBATCH";
GhostArg[2] = "-dSAFER";
GhostArg[3] = "-dNOPAUSE";
GhostArg[4] = "-g2480x3508";
GhostArg[5] = "-dPDFFitPage";
GhostArg[6] = "-r300x300";
GhostArg[7] = "-sDEVICE=ps2write";
GhostArg[8] = Output;
GhostArg[9] = Input;
```

**Solution Update:**

I managed to fix this problem by insert this three lines between Arg[8] and Arg[9]:

```
GhostArg[9] = "-c";
GhostArg[10] = "<< /BeginPage { 0.99 0.99 scale 10 10 translate } >> setpagedevice";
GhostArg[11] = "-f";
```

Thanks to KenS for the /BeginPage hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your printer has a non-printable area. This is not uncommon, the paper handling needs to hold the paper while its being printed, and this can lead to some areas of the media not being printable.

If your content reaches to the edge of the media, its possible that the printer simple cannot print there, resulting in the content being cropped.

It is entirely possible to have ps2write drop the media content to a smaller size, but you can't have it (automatically) scale down and also shift the content location, because the content is fitted to the media size.

However, the FitPage mechanism doesn't look at the content, just the media size requests. So if the input requests A3 and the selected media is A4 (and fixed) then a scale factor is applied to scale the content to the required media size (and the media request for A3 is ignored).

So what you could do is leave the code you have as it is as present, but add a BeginPage or Install procedure which uses the scale operator to further reduce the size of marks on the page, and the translate operator to move the origin slightly so that the final content is centered.

Something like (example only, untested):

```
<<
  /BeginPage {
    0.95 0.95 scale
    16 20 translate
  }
>> setpagedevice
```

By the way, you do realise Ghostscript is licenced under the AGPL ?

Also, I'd very strongly recommend that you do not use the -g and -r switches, but instead simply use -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS and -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS to alter the media size.

The -g switch works in pixels, but high level output devices (eg pdfwrite and ps2write) don't emit pixels, they write high level vector objects. However, due to differences in the PostScript and PDF graphics models, some elements do need to be rendered to images and enclosed in that fashion in the PostScript output. By setting the resolution to 300 you are fixing the resolution at which those elements (eg pages containing transparency) are rendered. I'd suggest that you don't do so, unless you are working in a very tightly controlled workflow and know the resolution of the final output.

By using the DEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS and DEVICEWIDTHPOINTS switches you can control the media size without reference to the resolution. Note that in PostScript (and PDF) 1 point = 1/72 inch.

Comment: I tried adding the /BeginPage (..) with the `-c` and `-f` switch, but this is resulting in no output anymore, maybe i can't use it with PDFFitPage at the same time?
I don't modify the original SourceCode, just use it as a library so i can use it in a managed context. Means, i don't have to redistribute my code?
Howewer, i know the resolution of the final output everytime, but i think i will change my code to -dDEVICE* from -g*x*.

Comment: If you're using a library, (presumably DLL) then you do have to conform to the AGPL as I understand it, because your users need to be able to replace the 'library' you are using with a different one, potentially of a different version, which means the API might have changed. If that happens they need to be able to modify your source, which is why you need to AGPL your code. Of course, I Am Not A Lawyer, your interpretation may differ. You should be able to use the BeginPage with -dFitPage but I haven't (as I said) tried it. You could try using /Install instead of /BeginPage. I'll try it later.

Comment: Hm, i use this API: https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.02/API.htm. Just from using Google i'm not sure about the Licence, the only thing i do is using the library for personal use, so i'm not sure about redistributing it (since i don't touch their DLL just use the header & lib file and export a method on my own DLL created for my needs to managed code...)
I tried both with FitPage and without, without GS will only use a "piece" of the sheet when creating the PS. I Updated my question with my solution; the scale and translate commands did it for me.

Comment: If its personal use you're fine anyway, its only supplying the code, or a service using the code, to other people that's a problem. Personal use is always OK. Oh, and I'm glad it did work for you :-)